# ¿Cómo detectar perdida de conexión en BD Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

**Situación**

Estoy investigando cómo detectar la perdida de conexión de una aplicación modelo cliente servidor con una base de datos oracle, concretamente por perdida de conexión de red (ejemplo, apagar la conexión a internet en el cliente)

**Alternativas probadas**

Hipotesis 1: El la tabla `V$SESSION` puedo detectar la desconexión:

Una vez un usuario se logea, se crea un registro en la tabla `V$SESSION`, en donde los campos `SID` y `SERIAL#` identifican la sesión del usuario, pero observo que cuando se presenta desconexión el registro se borra.

**Entorno**

- Base de datos: Oracle 11g
- CORE 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: ¿te refieres a detectarlo desde el servidor?

Comment: @rnd si, desde el servidor.

Comment: Desde el servidor puedes comprobar en estado con el comando `lsnrctl status`